I believe my question should be reopened
I had a question closed for the reason that "Questions on current or future market values, energy costs or service provider availability are off-topic".
Of those 3 possible reasons, it seems my question was closed for the "current or future market values" reason.  Based on how my question was originally worded, I can understand why it was closed for that reason.
However, my question wasn't really about why GBTC and Bitcoin moved a certain amount in one particular day.  My question is about why GBTC doesn't do what Grayscale says it is supposed to do on most days.
I have edited the question to reflect that, and I believe it should be reopened.
EDIT: I have found an Investor's Business Daily article that discusses why GBTC does not track Bitcoin.  If my question can be reopened, I will post an answer citing the article. 

I was not responsible for the leave closed/reopen decision, however, I doubt your question would attract more than low-quality opinion-based answers. It is really a question for Grayscale, even though you say that they have declined to respond.

If my question is on-topic now, then it should be reopened.  There are ways to deal with low quality answers if they show up.
Also, there are articles that discuss how GBTC does not track Bitcoin exactly.  If no one else answers, I will post my own answer using information from this article.

@pacoverflow May I suggest if it is reopened that you may wish to post what you have as an answer anyway.
